# How to write routes when a Rails app accepts request from API gateway?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-6

We have an API gateway. It transmits requests to many microservices.

For example, when a user hits `api.domain.com/product/categories`, it transmits the request to `product-service`, and the request is handled by `categories#index` in `product-service`.

Another example, the request `api.domain.com/geo/v1/locations/1` is handled by `v1/locations#show(:id)` in `geo-service`.

So far so good for APIs.

The problem is that our APIs and admin pages are mixed in one service.

Imagine in `geo-service`, I have the following routes:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :locations
  end

  namespace :v1 do
    resources :locations
  end
end
```

Everything works well when a user opens `api.domain.com/geo/admin/locations` in the browser, but the links in index page all become like `api.domain.com/admin/locations/1` so that the API gateway cannot transmit this request to our `geo-service`.

I tried to make my routes like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope '/geo' do
    namespace :admin do
      resources :locations
    end
  end

  namespace :v1 do
    resources :locations
  end
end
```

Then users have to type `api.domain.com/geo/geo/admin/locations` into my `admin/locations#index` page, while the links in the page become `api.domain.com/geo/admin/locations/1`. It still doesn't match, because the URL is available for `api.domain.com/geo/geo/admin/locations/1` this time.

Any ideas on how should I write these routes in Rails? I cannot modify the API gateway :(

Comment: You can create a constraint based on the subdomain or request path. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#request-based-constraints

Comment: @max I'm still not sure about how to use `constraints`. Is it possible for URL helpers to generate paths with a prefix globally (so that API gateway can transmit properly) while it doesn't have that prefix (or say removes the prefix) when mapping urls to controllers?

Comment: OMG! I add an env var called `SCRIPT_NAME` and it works! `SCRIPT_NAME=/geo rails s` and all links on /geo/admin are prefixed with '/geo' while API endpoint is not affected.